# Scrapy- Is there any way to clear cookies by spider

Tags: scrapy

I am crawling a website through scrapy. After a bunch of requests, the spider is stopping which means there is no pagination. When I open the same in browser it is showing me as `Please close the browser and try again Or return to the home page and try again`, But when I do inspect element and clear cookies in Resources tab I am able to view the page again...

How do I clear the cookies now with my spider???? I have added download_delay as 4 but still I see the same problem

Comment: could you please post the start-url ?

Comment: @Jithin https://www.werk.nl/werk_nl/werknemer/vacatures

Comment: You should paste the spider code. Otherwise, `request.cookies={}` should do it.

Comment: Hi I tried it but it is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable cookies within your `settings.py` file. Set:

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```